# How to download m3u8 files using ffmpeg using ffmpeg-cli-wrapper in java?

Tags: java, ffmpeg, m3u8

I am able to download m3u8 chuncks in on cli using following command,
ffmpeg -i "URL of m3u8 file" "outputm3u8.m3u8"

How can download this m3u8 chuncks using ffmpeg-cli-wrapper in java ?

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me:

```
FFmpeg ffmpeg = new FFmpeg("D:\\Programme\\ffmpeg-20180411-9825f77-win64-static\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe");
FFmpegBuilder job = ffmpeg.builder()
        .setInput("https://nhks-vh.akamaihd.net/i/news/easy/k10011478521000.mp4/master.m3u8")
        .addOutput("master.m3u8")
        .done();

new FFmpegExecutor(ffmpeg).createJob(job).run();
```

Put in the path to your local ffmpeg exe, set the input url and set the output name.